# Knockout.js nested ObservableArrays filtered by value at foreach

Tags: knockout.js, ko.observablearray

Good evening fellows. I'm trying to build an bootstrap tab dynamically with data sent from the server via Ajax. Inside every tab there is certain elements from another json source. Lets say:

```
Model A:
  id
  name

Model B:
 id
 name
 fk_a
```

My observable arrays takes all the objects from A and all the objects from B and what I'm trying to  achieve is to filter the elements of B from the current element at the Model A foreach:

```
<div class="tab-content" data-bind="foreach: arrayA">
    <div class="tab-pane" data-bind="attr: { id: 'div_grupo_' + $data.id }">
         <!-- A foreach here of modelB filtered by modelA value -->
    </div>
</div>
```

So far, I have find someways to filter an observable array but I can't find the way to pass the parameter to the function who filters the array. I could set an

Here the ViewModel

```
function Grupo(id, nombre){
            var self = this;
            self.id = id;
            self.nombre = nombre;
        };

        function Subgrupo(id, nombre, grupo){
            var self = this;
            self.id = id;
            self.nombre = nombre;
            self.grupo = grupo
        }


        function MainConsultaViewModel() {
            var self = this;
            self.grupos = ko.observableArray();
            self.subgrupos = ko.observableArray();

            self.filtroSubgrupos = ko.observable();

            this.subgruposPorGrupo = ko.computed(function() {
                var filtro = this.filtroSubgrupos();
                return ko.utils.arrayFilter(this.subgrupos(), function(filtro) {
                    return subgrupo.grupo == filtro;
                });
            }, this);

            var cambiaFiltro = function(valor){
                self.filtroSubgrupos(valor);
            }

            $.getJSON('some/url', function(data){
                $.each(data.objects, function (i, val) {
                    self.grupos.push(new Grupo(val.id, val.nombre));
                });
                console.log(self.grupos());
            });

            $.getJSON('some/other/url'+self.tipo_consulta, function(data){
                $.each(data.objects, function (i, val) {
                    self.subgrupos.push(new Subgrupo(val.id, val.nombre));
                });
            });

        };

        ko.applyBindings(new MainConsultaViewModel());
```

What I'm missing here? Is it possible to achieve this?

Cheers

Comment: Have a look at [another example](http://jsfiddle.net/origineil/J5QND/) closer to your original implementation that contains usages for both an event based filter (observable + computed) and a function that accepts the filter criteria.

Comment: this looks far more closer, either way it works. You could edit your answer and add this implementation too and I'll gladly mark it as correct. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`ko.utils.arrayFilter` Solution** :

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/origineil/J5QND/) keeping with the `ko.util.arrayFilter` usage.

1. If a selection event will be affecting the group by which to filter, you could use an `observable + computed` combination where the computed performs the filtering.
2. If the data is static and simply needs filtering upon render, you would pass the "current" group to a function that performs the filtering.

   Both scenarios detailed in the provided example link.

**Alternative Solution**: [Alias (Note 3)](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html) your data and use an [if binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/if-binding.html) to perform the filtering.

[Example:](http://jsfiddle.net/origineil/CLMby/)

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: {data: A, as: 'dataA'}">
  <li><span data-bind="text: dataA.id "></span></li>
  <ul data-bind="foreach: {data: $root.B, as: 'dataB'}">
    <div data-bind="if: $root.equals(dataA, dataB)">
        <li> <span data-bind="text: dataB.other "></span></li>
    </div>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: Looks like promising. The example works and for what I need it might work. But It would be nice to know if there's a way to achieve this filtering. But it might work. Thanks!